# Titanium- JavaScript : How to set check mark of a particular row if the values of row existed in a selected array

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I was very new to titanium and java script

I have **populated a table view with an array** ***`myArray`***

as follows

***`$.table.setData(myArray);`***

in that myArray contains `JSon formatted values` like ***`(title:value1, title:value2)`***

And i have an another array '***`selectedArray`***' of selected values

Now i **need to check each row values that it was existed in   'selectedArray' or not**

if it was already existed in  'selectedArray' then we need to disply a check marK

how to achieve this can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 basic ways:

1. You can maintain single array and add a field named selected (true/false)
2. While adding the elements to myArray you can check for same element in selectedArray and add checkmark accordingly